# Why does my code dividing a 2D array into chunks fail?

Tags: java

I have a 2D-Array representing my world. I want to divide this huge thing into smaller chunks to make collision detection easier.

I have a `Chunk` class that consists only of another 2D `Array` with a specific width and height and I want to iterate through the world, create new `Chunk`s and add them to a list (or maybe a `Map` with `Coordinates` as the key; we'll see about that).

```
world = new World(8192, 1024);

Integer[][] chunkArray;

for(int a = 0; a < map.getHeight() / Chunk.chunkHeight; a++)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < map.getWidth() / Chunk.chunkWidth; b++)
    {
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk();
        chunkArray = new Integer[Chunk.chunkWidth][Chunk.chunkHeight];

        for(int x = Chunk.chunkHeight*a; x < Chunk.chunkHeight*(a+1); x++)
        {
            for(int y = Chunk.chunkWidth*b; y < Chunk.chunkWidth*(b+1); y++)
            {
                // Yes, the tileMap actually is [height][width] I'll have
                // to fix that somewhere down the line -.-
                chunkArray[y][x] = map.getTileMap()[x*a][y*b];
                // TODO:Attach to chunk
            }
        }

        chunkList.add(chunk);
    }
}

System.out.println(chunkList.size());
```

The two outer loops get a new chunk in a specific row and column. I do that by dividing the overall size of the map by the `chunkSize`.

The inner loops then fill a new `chunkArray` and attach it to the chunk. But somehow my maths is broken here.

Let's assume the `chunkHeight = chunkWidth = 64`.

For the first Array I want to start at `[0][0]` and go until `[63][63]`. For the next I want to start at `[64][64]` and go until `[127][127]` and so on. But I get an out of bounds exception and can't figure out why.

Any help appreciated!

**Actually I think I know where the problem lies:**

`chunkArray[y][x]` can't work, because `y` goes from 0-63 just in the first iteration. Afterwards it goes from 64-127, so sure it is out of bounds.

Still no nice solution though :/

**EDIT:**

```
if(y < Chunk.chunkWidth && x < Chunk.chunkHeight)
    chunkArray[y][x] = map.getTileMap()[y][x];
```

This works for the first iteration... now I need to get the commonly accepted formula.

Comment: Is `Chunk.chunkWidth` a const int size? If so what value have you given it?

Comment: Both, width and height are public static final Integer = 64; Sorry, I thought that was clear from my description (non-native speaker, sorry!)

Comment: You mentioned "Lets assume the chunkHeight" but if they are static finals then they cannot change, so assumption is not necessary.

Comment: Ya, you're right. I cannot change them at runtime, but I can change them before compiling. But what I meant was the basic maths :)

Comment: Are you sure you have to create a `chunkArray` at all? If it's just for collision detection, couldn't you still work on the original world array, but instead of checking all of it, limit the checks to a certain area of interets?

Comment: Have you tried looking into quadtrees? They are an especially useful tool for 2D collision detection and may be just what you are looking for.

Comment: I will be using Box2D and I want to only load chunks that are on screen. :)

Comment: This question has an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think we could edit it to ask "How do I do X" (with your solution as an answer) instead of "What is the bug in my implementation of X". That would yield a more generally useful question and be a lot clearer to read. Do you think that would work?

Comment: Ah, ok, so you want the chunks for loading, not for collision detection.

Comment: Any luck on your solution?

Answer (score 2):

Note that even though your `chunkArray` instances are all supposed to cover different areas of your world, their indices still all range from `0` to `Chunk.chunkWidth` and `0` to `Chunk.chunkHeight` respectively.

Therefore, you should make sure that whenever you access `chunkArray` the `x-` and `y-` indices do not go out of these ranges. The easiest way to make sure they won't is to actually change the two inner-most for-loops like so:

```java
int offsetX = b * Chunk.chunkWidth;
int offsetY = a * Chunk.chunkHeight;
Integer[][] tileMap = map.getTileMap();

for(int y = 0; y < Chunk.chunkHeight; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < Chunk.chunkWidth; x++)
    {
        chunkArray[x][y] = tileMap[offsetX + x][offsetY + y];
    }
}
```

A faster way to achieve the same thing would be to use the built-in `System.arraycopy`:

```java
int offsetX = b * Chunk.chunkWidth;
int offsetY = a * Chunk.chunkHeight;
Integer[][] tileMap = map.getTileMap();

for(int x = 0; x < Chunk.chunkWidth; x++)
{
   System.arraycopy(tileMap[offsetX + x], offsetY, chunkArray[x], 0, Chunk.chunkHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my two cents:

All the work can be found on here too so you can run it and see how it works http://ideone.com/xKWAip

Separate it into pieces and you can see how it'll work with a wee access expression after flattening the initial map array.

Here is what I used to generate your map (at the moment it's square only but as long as your width and length are divisible by your chunk size you're fine):

```
public static int[][] GenMap(int mapSize)
{
    int[][] arrayStuff = new int[mapSize][mapSize];
    for (int x = 0; x < mapSize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapSize; y++)
        {
            arrayStuff[x][y] = y + (mapSize * x);
        }
    }
    return arrayStuff;
}
```

Here we Generate the chunks by flattening the map array and then using a chunk map coordinate of `(i, j)` and a chunk coordinate of `(x, y)` to then look through x and y within `i` and `j`.

Once that is looped through you can use the expression: `y + (x * mapLength) + (chunkSize * i) + (chunkSize * mapLength * j)` to find the index of the flattened array, providing the values you need in a `[0, 1, 2, 3], [16, 17, 18, 19], [32, 33, 34, 35], [48, 49, 50, 51]` format for your chunk info.

```
public static List<int[][]> GenChunks(int[][] map, int mapLength, int chunkSize)
{ 
    int[] inputArray = new int[map.length * map[0].length];
    for(int a = 0; a < map.length; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < map[0].length; b++)
        {
            inputArray[(a * map.length) + b] = map[a][b];
        }
    }

    List<int[][]> chunksList = new ArrayList<int[][]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mapLength / chunkSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapLength / chunkSize; j++)
        {
            int[][] newChunk = new int[chunkSize][];

            for (int x = 0; x < chunkSize; x++)
            {
                newChunk[x] = new int[chunkSize];

                for (int y = 0; y < chunkSize; y++)
                {
                    int offset = j * chunkSize * mapLength;
                    newChunk[y][x] = inputArray[y + (x * mapLength) + (chunkSize * i) + (chunkSize * mapLength * j)];
                }
            }

            chunksList.add(newChunk);
        }
    }

    return chunksList;
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int mapSize = 8;
    int chunkSize = 2;

    int[][] mapArray = GenMap(mapSize);

    System.out.println("Start chunks");

    List<int[][]> chunks;
    chunks = GenChunks(mapArray, mapSize , chunkSize);
 }
```